Потрясающее путешествие в мир Stack Overflow (издание 2024) 
Читала книгу "Lessons Learned While Working on Stack Overflow: Уроки, полученные при работе над Stack Overflow" на протяжении пяти часов. Эти пять часов пролетели словно одно мгновение, оставляя мурашки по коже и вызывая бурю эмоций.
Я не могу не поделиться своими впечатлениями с вами, это было бы просто эгоистично)))
Вот ссылка на покупку
Книга состоит из трех частей, каждая из которых увлекает по-своему:

To do pull ups, you need to do pull ups: Первая часть рассказывает о том, как решимость и настойчивость могут привести к великим результатам. Она наполнена полезными уроками и советами, которые можно применить в жизни и карьере.
Playing in the Premier League: Вторая часть переносит нас в мир профессионалов, где работа требует высокого уровня мастерства и ответственности. Здесь Николас делится опытом работы в команде Stack Overflow.
The Fall of the Star: Третья часть раскрывает драматические моменты и внутренние конфликты, которые сопровождали создание и развитие сайта. Это история о взлетах и падениях, которые делают нас сильнее. А также небольшие инсайты о том, что происходило "за кулисами" StackOverflow последние года.

Читала я книгу с помощью переводчика, так как английский не знаю, но это вовсе не уменьшило интереса и не помешало следить за мыслью автора. Николас рассказывает о зарождении Stack Overflow на русском языке, как он еще был HashCode-ом. Волны мурашек накрывали меня, когда я прочитывала историю его становления, эмоциональные переживания, а порой и гордость за проделанный труд.

"Есть две основные силы, объединяющие людей в большие группы: интерес к теме и желание иметь тесные связи с другими людьми."

Книга также содержит множество советов по созданию и управлению сообществом, описывает внутреннюю кухню работы в команде Stack Overflow. История драмы и зарождения сообщества рассказывается с таким трепетом и эмоциональным подтекстом, что за время прочтения мне удалось словно пережить все это вместе с автором.

"Сообщество – это живой организм, меняющийся с течением времени."

Эти слова глубоко проникают в сердце и заставляют задуматься о важности каждого члена сообщества и о том, как мы можем стать лучше, помогая друг другу.
Время прочтения прошло в миг. Книга нашла свое заслуженное место среди любимых книг на моей полке. Спасибо автору за книгу и StackOverflow на русском!

"Чтобы не случилось, мы всегда должны оставаться людьми. Мы должны быть добры к другим и предполагать добрые намерения."

Особенно хотелось бы отметить замечательные мысли из книги:

"Ответственность без сострадания приводит к грубости."
"Сострадание без ответственности приводит к бездействию."

Эти фразы заставляют задуматься о важности баланса в жизни и отношениях с другими людьми

P.S. С таким прекрасным чтивом и чашечкой какао можно наслаждаться долгими вечерами!


Ну что ж он её не на русском-то написал? (((

А про конфликты, методы их разрешения, и две волны исхода участников там рассказано?

@VladD, эм, вы про сайт карьера, тот период ? Там как бы все поверхностно/компактно охвачено страниц то 200,а не 2000))), но тк я ещё и там тут смотрела разные видео, интервью, читала отсюда оттуда, то у меня была общая картина. Тут конечно снимаю шляпу, что "идею" пронесли несмотря на боль

Я сочту за благородство, если тема тут на этом остановится))). И кстати пользуясь случаем, хотелось вам сказать спасибо, что вы не смотря ни на что, остались таким простым и хорошим человеком. Это очень дорого и ценно

Насчет конфликтов и исходов есть альтернативная история: https://github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/ruso-archive/blob/master/articles/drama.md

Кстати, в книге есть точная дата запуска Stackoverflow на русском? По приблизительным данным, это где-то в июле 2015 года. Через год должен быть десятилетний юбилей (если без периода Хэшкода).

@VladD ты ещё про ситуацию с Моникой вспомни (¬‿¬ )

https://i.sstatic.net/wjCX0WPY.jpg

@Suvitruf: я бы скорее вспомнил эту статью. Туда приходил Паша, пытался защищать позицию руководства (своими обычными методами).

@MSDN.WhiteKnight: потрясающий архив, спасибо, прямо вернулся в прошлое

@VladD уже 5 лет прошло...
